# pass a while loop in Tsql / multiple values for one variable to exec proc

Tags: stored-procedures, while-loop, ssis, parameter-passing

I've been trying to resolve this since a while, still couldn't figure out how to apply a while value like:

```
while ....(having values in (X1, X2, X3, ........)
     (
      execute 'package....'
      Param = X
      )
```

passing every time the one of the values of X, X1 then X2 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass all params to temporary table and then loop them using `WHILE`:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), param_value NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO #tab(param_value)
VALUES (@X1), (@X2),  (@X3); -- ...

DECLARE @counter INT = 1,
        @param NVARCHAR(MAX);

WHILE @counter <= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM #tab)
BEGIN
   SELECT @param = param_value
   FROM #tab
   WHERE id = @counter;

   EXEC [dbo].[my_stored_proc]
         @param;

   SET @counter += 1;
END
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f6d7f/1/0)**</kbd>